# Prove $B_n\le n! $ for Bell numbers

Tags: induction, bell-numbers

How using induction it can be shown that:

> $$B_n\le n! \;\;\;\;\;\;\;\;\;\left( n\in \mathbb N \right)$$

Where $B_n$ is the nth [Bell number](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bell_number).

The base case is true, since $$1=B_0\le 0!=1 \;\;\;\;\;\;\;\;\;\text{and}\;\;\;\;\;\;\;\;\; 1=B_1\le 1!=1$$

Assume the relation holds for $n=k$ and consider $n=k+1$:

This is where I cannot continue, I tried to use the relation $B_{k+1}\ge kB_{k-1}+B_k$, but that did not help me.

---

Comment: You can use the recurrence [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/289016/partitions-and-bell-numbers?rq=1).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Hint:**

Consider instead the identity (listed on the [Wikipedia page](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bell_number#Properties)):

$$B_{n+1} = \sum_{k=0}^n \binom{n}{k} B_k$$

Then by (strong) induction, we know each $B_k \leq k!$, so:

$$
B_{n+1} = 
\sum_{k=0}^n \binom{n}{k} B_k \leq
\sum_{k=0}^n \binom{n}{k} k! =
\sum_{k=0}^n \frac{n!}{(n-k)!}
$$

Can you take it from here?

---

I hope this helps ^_^

Comment: Ah, now I see what I've missed in my own attempts (+1)!

Comment: $$\sum_{k=0}^{n}\frac{n!}{\left(n-k\right)!}\le\sum_{k=0}^{n}n!=\left(n+1\right)n!=\left(n+1\right)!$$ right?

Comment: Looks good to me! ^_^

Comment: @ very simple and fast (+1), thanks.