# Relation between Bell number and $F(n)$ the number of partitions of $[n]$ without singeton blocks

Tags: combinatorics, limits, set-partition, bell-numbers

Let $F(n)$ be the number of all partitions of $[n]$ with no singleton blocks.
Prove that
$$\lim_{n\to\infty}\frac{F(n)}{B(n)}=0$$

According to [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/289016/partitions-and-bell-numbers), we can know
$$F(n+1)=\sum_{i=0}^{n-1}(-1)^iB(n-i)$$
[Bell numbers](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bell_number) have the property
$$B(n+1)=\sum_{i=0}^n\begin{pmatrix}
n\\i
\end{pmatrix}B(i)$$
so
$$\begin{aligned}
\lim_{n\to\infty}\frac{F(n+1)}{B(n+1)}&=\lim_{n\to\infty}\frac{\sum_{i=0}^{n-1}(-1)^iB(n-i)}{\sum_{i=0}^n\begin{pmatrix}
n\\i
\end{pmatrix}B(i)}\\
&=\frac{B(n)-B(n-1)\cdots}{B(n)+\begin{pmatrix}
n\\n-1
\end{pmatrix}B(n-1)\cdots}
\end{aligned}
$$
I think $B(n)\gg B(n-1)$ so it is equal to $1$ not $0$.

How to prove it? Thanks!

Comment: Set partitions without singletons are tabulated, with much information at http://oeis.org/A000296

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assume $n\gt2$.

Let $G(n)$ be the number of partitions of $[n]$ into **at least** $\sqrt n$ non-singleton blocks, and let $H(n)$ be the number of partitions of $[n]$ into **at most** $\sqrt n$ non-singleton blocks.

$F(n)\le G(n)+H(n)$, so $\max\{G(n),H(n)\}\ge\frac12F(n)$.

Let $B'(n)=B(n)-F(n)$, the number of partitions of $[n]$ with at least one singleton block.

$B'(n)\ge\sqrt nG(n)$ because we can turn any $G(n)$-partition into at least $\sqrt n$ different $B'(n)$-partitions by breaking one of its blocks into singletons, and each $B'(n)$-partition obtained in this way has a unique source.

$B'(n)\ge\sqrt nH(n)$, because we can turn any $H(n)$-partition into a $B'(n)$-partition by choosing an element of $[n]$ and making it a singleton block, and no $B'(n)$-partition is obtained in more than $\sqrt n$ ways.

It follows that
$$B(n)-F(n)=B'(n)\ge\sqrt n\max\{G(n),H(n)\}\ge\frac{\sqrt n}2F(n),$$
so
$$B(n)\ge\frac{\sqrt n+2}2F(n)$$
and
$$\frac{F(n)}{B(n)}\le\frac2{\sqrt n+2}\to0\text{ as }n\to\infty.$$